# How to get a range of cells while retaining their format from an .xlsx document?

Tags: python, excel, win32com

I am trying to print a range of cells from xlsx to pdf using below code

```
from win32com import client

xlApp = client.Dispatch("Excel.Application")
books = xlApp.Workbooks.Open('C:\\Users\....\\2020.xlsx')
ws = books.Worksheets['TEST']
ws.Visible = 1
ws.ExportAsFixedFormat(0, 'C:\\Users\.....\\trial.pdf')
```

This code works fine. However, I would like to tweak to print only the cells ranging from `A1` to `K50`; and should retain the cell formatting from excel when converted to PDF. Is this possible?

Comment: I'm no expert, but it might be easier to do with one of the several third-party modules that exist that can read Excel files (than it would be using win32com).

Comment: based on my research, other third party products require excel to be converted to html & perform all custom styling then print to pdf. There is no direct print for range of cells

Answer (score 0):

It is very hard to format using python code with other third party packages. Below solution is useful when either the formatting requires a lot of effort or when the formatting may be dynamic & you may need to just print the excel like the way it is:

This solution is done using the below code (note the trick is using `IgnorePrintAreas=False`), however, the ranges that I wanted to print I set it up as the [printable range](https://www.excel-easy.com/examples/print-area.html) on excel. This will print the range that I am interested in & with the format that is present in Excel.

```
from win32com import client
xlApp = client.Dispatch("Excel.Application")
books = xlApp.Workbooks.Open('C:\\Users\....\\2020.xlsx')
ws = books.Worksheets['TEST']
ws.Visible = 1
ws.ExportAsFixedFormat(0, 'C:\\Users\.....\\trial.pdf',IgnorePrintAreas=False)
```